# Can PHP detect whether or not Apache is sending a default charset header?

Tags: php

In the Apache config, one can set the following directive to cause the httpd to always send a UTF-8 character encoding header for text/html and text/plain MIME types:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

I would like to be able to detect in my PHP scripts whether or not this header is being sent, so that I can send the same header using the `header()` function if it hasn't been sent.

How can I detect this?

Comment: Why not simply always set the header?

Comment: I don't really want to send it twice, and I especially want to avoid the header sent by Apache disagreeing with the one sent by PHP.

Comment: I believe Apache will not overwrite the header if you set it, so no sending twice.

Comment: Yes, you appear to be correct - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information provided by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze%20deceze) in the comments on the initial question negated a need for an answer. However, for the sake of completeness, I would say that it appears that there isn't an obvious way to detect if headers have been sent by Apache from within PHP... but, given the above information, I can't think of a reason why you'd need to.

Answer (score 2):

There's [apache_response_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php), though it'll only report on headers that are already "in play". If your charset header is added after the fact, you'd never see it.

Comment: Sorry. bad cut 'n paste on my part. there's also apache_response_headers. fixing the answer in 5... 4...